# Why Do I Get a Segmentation Fault with this C Code?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

This code gives me a segmentation fault:

```
char *s1 = "String 1", *s2 = "String 2";
void swap(char **, char **);

int main(void) {
    swap(&s1, &s2);
    return 0;
}

void swap(char **p, char **q) {
    char **tmp;

    *tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = *tmp;
}
```

But if I change the body of the last function to this code it doesn't make any problems:

```
    char *tmp;

    tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
```

I really don't understand why am I getting a segmentation fault with the first code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: what's the difference between `tmp` and `*tmp` if `tmp` is a pointer to something?

Comment: Your first version would work (inefficiently) if it were `char* tempmem; char **tmp = &tempmem; ...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `tmp` pointer is uninitialized and you dereference it in the very next line. That's undefined behaviour, which includes the possibility of a segfault.

Comment: @Robert777 when you say "fixed" do you mean you changed your code to the second implementation you showed in your post, where `tmp` is a `char *` or did you do something else? If something else, I'd be curious to see what.

Comment: @Robert777, That won't work: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2Pddhp%244. To elaborate, when you say `*p = *q`, `tmp` changes as well because it points to the same thing as `p`.

Comment: @Nik-Bougalis, Yes you're correct. I didn't try to print it and just looked at compile warnings.