# segmentation fault when trying to get the pointer to an int

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault when trying to run the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

    int* tes1;
    int* tes2;

    *tes1=55;

    *tes2=88;



    printf("int1 %p int2 %p \n",tes1,tes2);

    return 0;
}
```

why is that?

Comment: Didn't I [answer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844783/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-with-this-c-code/15844795#15844795) not too long ago? :p

Comment: obviously that did not stick, @chris

Comment: @scones, Well, it isn't the same asker, but it does answer why there's a segfault.

Comment: @chris well, there are obviously 5,295 - 1 reasons for segfaults according to search. the ought to be some redundancy.

Comment: @Fazlan when your pointers point to regions of memory and use that, that you do not own (by requesting it from the OS), you get a segfault (or access violation).

Comment: Thank you :). I have been silly to dereference an uninitialized pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate the pointers, otherwise they point to garbage memory:

```
int* tes1; //random initial value
int* tes2; //random initial value
```

In order to make them point to assignable memory, use the `malloc` function:

```
int* tes1 = malloc(sizeof(int)); //amount of memory to allocate (in bytes)
int* tes2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Then you safely use the pointers:

```
*tes1=55;
*tes2=88;
```

But when you're done, you should free the memory using the `free` function:

```
free(tes1);
free(tes2);
```

This will release the memory back to the system and prevent a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring pointers, and then trying to define values of pointer of the pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int* tes1;
    int* tes2;
    tes1=55; //remove the * here
    tes2=88;
    printf("int1 %p int2 %p \n",tes1,tes2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if they want what it's pointing to to be 55 or 88? That's the intention I got from the question.

Comment: No, i'm pretty sure that he's declaring pointers and then trying to assign value to the memory that they point to. Also, you cannot assign integer value to pointers directly.